# What in-game hints are given for the evolution of Feebas?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-third-generation

Feebas evolves into Milotic either by significantly increasing its 'beauty' stat or by trading it while holding a Prism Scale. Both of these triggers for evolution, as far as I know, are unique to Feebas.

A friend of mine has recently started playing Pokemon, starting with Ruby, and aims to fill the Pokedex as much as possible without any outside advice. He was lucky enough to backtrack and find Feebas with little effort but is not using it in his main team.

From my own recollection of Gen. 3, there were never any in-game hints as to how to evolve Feebas. I either found out by looking at a guide or being told by someone else. Is my own recollection of Ruby, Sapphire and Emerald incomplete, or were there really no hints given in the games on how to get Milotic?

Comment: I've always thought it's a conspiracy to get people to shell out for those Prima guidebooks

Comment: It's been ages since I last played it, but I think it was referred to by one of the NPCs in one of the contest huts.

Comment: The thing about pokemon games is that there are a lot of NPCS you can talk to.  I get the feeling one of them gives a hint or tells you (but I haven't played it enough to confirm).

Comment: I've just searched a Pokemon Platinum text dump (found at https://gist.githubusercontent.com/superusercode/4fcc41719deef5d5c21cca0bd295118a/raw/80cab2b3fac8a8f2f13f2203dfc7d229547405bb/pokemon-platinum-text-dump-en.txt) for the terms "beaut", "contest", "poffin", "feebas", "milotic", "evol" and "turned". I can't find anything in the strings. However, sometimes the original Japanese text isn't translated properly, and as such it might be possible that there is a reference in the original Japanese text, but not in the english text.

Comment: As an addendum to my previous comment: I did find a string that said "Are you aware that there is more than one style of evolution? There are some Pokémon that evolve by becoming friends with the Trainer." The original Japanese string might use a term for "becoming friends" which also has a reference to beauty.

Comment: I think there's a reference of Feebas being the ugliest and Milotic the most beautiful Pokemon, so it's kinda hinted at, but actually getting that hint and realizing how to do this is probably nearly as hard as figuring out how to evolve Inkay. Side note, there is no Prism Scale in Gen 3, that was added later in order to be able to evolve Feebas in games without the beauty mechanic.

Comment: @scenia A number of pokedex entries do indeed refer to Feebas being shabby and largely ignored. There may have been some NPC text lost in translation that points to a hint.

Comment: Should we ask the guy at http://legendsoflocalization.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Most evolution requirements aren't revealed in-game.**

I have played through Gen 3 many times, it being the first pokemon game I had and it also working on an emulator on my laptop.

In regards to the beauty stat, it is never mentioned in game as to the requirements for evolution, and Prism scale wasnt introduced until Gen 5 (as there wasn't a 'beauty' stat to raise in that Gen).

Comment: So, what hints were provided in-game to help figure out how to evolve Feebas?

Comment: @Frank As the answer says, there aren't any.

Comment: I know the Prism Scale wasn't introduced until later, but alas for the older games it would seem most of us either learned about it from gamer osmosis or looking at a guide.